# how insert data to server on client with database mysql with background worker vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
                   koneksiserver()



            Try


                Dim sqlinsert As String = "INSERT INTO sentitems (TextDecoded, " & _
                                 "DestinationNumber,SenderID,ID)" & _
                                 "VALUES(@isi,@nohp,@modem,@ID)"
                Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlinsert, MyCon)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@isi", MySqlDbType.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@nohp", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@modem", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int16)




                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 0
                    cmd.Parameters("@isi").Value = DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                    cmd.Parameters("@nohp").Value = DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                    cmd.Parameters("@modem").Value = DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                    cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Next
                DisplayStatus("Conected...")
                isExecuting = True

                Dim callback As New AsyncCallback(AddressOf HandleCallback)
                cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, cmd)






                MyCon.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception






                'MyCon.Close()

                ' MsgBox("Export Berhasil", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "DHAPU SMS")

            End Try
    End Sub
Private Sub set_db_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles set_db.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()









    End Sub
```

Comment: Use a DataTable and DataAdapter and you wont have to loop thru anything and can likely dispense with the BGWorker

Answer (score 0):

Azmy;
Assuming that you are using a BackgroundWorker to prevent UI lockup:

You can not reference any objects tied to the UI thread, referring to DataGridView3,  DisplayStatus and MsgBox are guaranteed exceptions.

Also your loop
         For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 0

will fail because you are not adjusting the count properly  use a -1 not a minus 0

To accomplish what you want you must pass a table object or an array of data objects or what ever data you want updated through the System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs argument.

Comment: I never performs it..but data can't save to database online..if i'm insert to database local work..what wrong..?